# Windows are open on my PC that allows me to hear the voices even though I can't see anything

Tags: windows-vista

I seriously need HELP.  It seems as though websites are open on my PC that I didn't open.  These allow me to hear voices of persons talking, music even commercials on those sites but I don't know which sites are open and the noises from these sites come on even while I am in a different location on the web.  How do I access those web sites to close the windows and eliminate the sounds altogether? It just happened even while I'm typing this to you.  PLEASE HELP ME!!!!

Desperate needin help

Comment: What browser are you using? Does it support multiple tabs? Are these sites open in the other tabs? Sometimes spammy websites have ads that pop up in another tab or window. It's possible that they may be positioned outside the edges of the screen. Does closing your browser completely make the extra audio stop?

Comment: Maybe you are getting a bit schizophrenic?

Comment: which browser you are using is it a firefox,chrome or ie?

Comment: Perhaps go try some things and come back with questions?

Comment: Sounds like you've missed your daily dose of Haldol.

Answer (score 1):

Your computer has been infected with spyware, adware or malware.  Most likely something you downloaded or installed or clicked on in an email or website installed an adware process that is running in the background.  Try scanning your PC with software designed to detect this, such as [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/).  This exact thing happened to me recently and every few minutes I would hear advertisements playing in the background.  I was finally able to track it down to a software utility I had installed that wasn't as honest as I thought it was.